# Sort repeats by frequency and length

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I am thinking about the best way of getting all unique repeats in a string and sorting them by length and repeat frequency (number)

I am starting with this code

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
{
  String s = "AAAABBBBAAAANNNNAAAABBBBNNNBBBBAAAA";
  Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\S{2,})(?=.*?\\1)").matcher(s);
  while (m.find())
  {
    for (int i = 1; i <= m.groupCount(); i++)
    {
      System.out.println(m.group(i));
    }
  }
}
```

and would like to have some suggestions of having such output :

AAAA 4 1,9,17,33
etc

where 4=Number of repeats, 1,9,17,33 the positions

I appreciate your help

Comment: Use a HashMap to map String to a List<Integer>

Comment: `HashMap<String, Set<Integer>>`. `String` = the string (AAAA), `Set<Integer>` is the indexes (1,9,17,33).

Comment: Actually, there is no need for Set - a List would suffice for storing the indices.

Comment: The first thing the current program ouputs is `AAAABBBB`.

Comment: But I am targeting several repeats not only one is that still possible with a HashMap ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, your pattern will not give you what you want. You should change your regex to: -

```
"(\\S)\\1+"
```

to get repetition of a single character.

Now to get the location and number of repeats, you can maintain a `Map<String, List<Integer>>`, to store the location of each repetition.

Also, you don't need that `for` loop inside the `while`. The while loop is enough to iterate through all the patterns.

Here's your modified code: -

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();

String s = "AAAABBBBAAAANNNNAAAABBBBNNNBBBBAAAA";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\S)\\1+").matcher(s);

while (m.find())
{
    String str = m.group();
    int loc = m.start();

    // Check whether the pattern is present in the map.
    // If yes, get the list, and add the location to it.
    // If not, create a new list. Add the location to it. 
    // And add new entry in map.

    if (map.containsKey(str)) {
        map.get(str).add(loc);

    } else {
        List<Integer> locList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        locList.add(loc);
        map.put(str, locList);
    }

}
System.out.println(map);
```

**Output : -**

```
{AAAA=[0, 8, 16, 31], BBBB=[4, 20, 27], NNNN=[12], NNN=[24]}
```

Comment: +1. But, a `LinkedList` would probably be better than an `ArrayList` in this situation for memory reasons. Probably won't matter though.

Comment: Maybe goes without saying but now the frequency is the length of the position list.

Comment: @durron597. Or, probably a `Set` would be better. Since location would be unique.

Comment: @RohitJain not really, because a `HashTable` (what underlies a `HashMap`) has lots of extra space available for Hash entries. A `LinkedList` would be minimum memory usage here.

Comment: @durron597.. Umm. Are you sure. I mean I'm not sure, whether I got you or not. But seems like `hashing` might be some extra work in case of `Set`. Couldn't really make out some difference is `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` in this case.